# convert a string into a list of floats

Tags: python

The string to be converted is:

```
strng= "0.000000000000000E+000, 2*2.400000000000000E-002  , 97*0.000000000000000E+000  ,"
```

which I was able to split using `strng.split(',')`

```
['  0.000000000000000E+000', ' 2*2.400000000000000E-002  ', ' 97*0.000000000000000E+000  ', '\n']
```

however  `' 2*2.400000000000000E-002  '` is not a string but actually two elemts of a list
and `' 97*0.000000000000000E+000` is actually 97 elements of a list.

Here is an ugly attempt to accomplish this:

```
  a=strng.split("=").split(',')
  lst=[]
  for item in a:
      print("intem=", item)
      i= item.split("*")
      if len(i) >1:
          print(int(i[0])*i[1])
          lst.append(int(i[0])*i[1])
      else:
           lst.append(i[0])
  print("================")
  print(lst)
```

What is a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: `97*0.000000000000000E+000 is actually 97 lists` - Could you explain this? What do you mean by this??

Comment: You editing before I could review the question. It is 97 elements of a list

Comment: 97 elements? you mean you want the same element to repeat 97 times in a sublist?

Comment: yes. 97 repeated elements in this case

Comment: Can you show how the elements look when they're repeated in the string? Your [mre] is not enough for us to understand, I think.

Comment: "however `' 2*2.400000000000000E-002  '` is not a string but actually two elemts of a list " That doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do this with string manipulations but this is only so that you for your understanding on how it works.

```
string = "0.000000000000000E+000, 2*2.400000000000000E-002  , 97*0.000000000000000E+000  ,"

out = [eval(i.strip().replace('*','*[')+']' if '*' in i else '['+i.strip()+']') for i in strng.split(',') if len(i)>0]

print(out)
```

```
[[0.0], [0.024, 0.024], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering

```
string = "0.000000000000000E+000, 2*2.400000000000000E-002  , 97*0.000000000000000E+000  ,"
```

You can apply the following steps:

1. Split and strip the original string:

```
# Split by commas
expressions = string.split(',')

# Remove leading and trailing white space of each element
expressions = [expression.strip() for expression in expressions] 

# Remove empty elements
expressions = [expression for expression in expressions if expression]
```

or, alternatively,

```
expressions = [expression.strip() for expression in string.split(',') if expression.strip()]
```

This will evaluate to

```
['0.000000000000000E+000', '2*2.400000000000000E-002', '97*0.000000000000000E+000']
```

2. Create a new list and evaluate each expression:

```
result = []
for expression in expressions:
    # Split by the multiplication sign
    operands = expression.split('*')

    # A single element, just add to `result`
    if len(operands) == 1:
        result.append(float(operands[0]))
        
    # Two operands, add to `result` repeatdely
    elif len(operands) == 2:
        o1, o2 = operands
        o1 = int(o1)
        o2 = float(o2)
        for _ in range(o1):
            result.append(o2)
```

This will evaluate to

```
[0.0, 0.024, 0.024, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```